# add command on ItemTemplate selection

Tags: c#, wpf, click, itemtemplate

This is a pretty easy question I think , but I can't find the answer. I have an itemtemplate defined into a datatemplate. When an item is selected, I wanna trigger a command to select the name of my element and apply it somewhere else. For the moment the MouseDown event doesn't accept my command.

```
<ListView Margin="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ExistingStateInfos, ElementName=Window}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedStateInfo, ElementName=Window}" x:Name="statinfoListview">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type States:StateInfo}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" MouseDown="{x:Static MyWindow.ApplyStateInfoNameToStateCommand}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a command directly to an event handler.

Use `EventToCommand` from the [MVVM LightToolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type States:StateInfo}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding YourCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I'm allowed to integrate this toolkit in the project (and we don't use MVVM here). Is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact ot was bulshit from me, I just add to do

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" MouseDown="{x:Static ApplyStateInfoNameToState_Click}" />
```

Sorry it's friday. Have a nice weekend :)